# Modeling Awkward Geo

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model what is shown in this image.  I'm new to Blender and struggling.  I've tried doing it as a curve with a Bevel > Object but I can't get it to 'twist' like it is shown in the image.  Can anyone help?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: It may be possible to make this in 3D, with some work, essentially fighting _against_ the natural 3D geometry, normals, lighting ... but this looks to me like a fundamentally 2D illustration.. e vector outline filled with gradients.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 3):

Use your image as reference, make a series of extrusions:

[image]

[image]

As you're about to bevel and you want your bevel to work, cut an edge somewhere in the middle:

[image]

Bevel:

[image]

Give it a material, put some lights:

[image]

Comment: Hehe.. you only have to make a comment like mine on the OP, and along comes ..  'boots' :)

Comment: I always need to try when you say that it's impossible

Comment: Thank you x1000! Brilliant answer.